# LinkedIn profile fetching not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api

I have integrated LinkedIn in my ASP.Net website and trying to read user profile data who logs in. I am accessing following URL but getting error. My application has authorized and got access token from LinkedIn.

URL
`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/MyAccessToken`

Error
`The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

It seems I am not using correct format to pass access token to this URL to get the data. Can someone please guide me on correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the accesstoken should be added as an Bearer-Token and the API path should be :

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/person_ID/
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a tutorial about adding bearer token?

Comment: there are guides on how to add an access token as bearer but not for linkedin specific. just google it and you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: Yes I got it. In ASP.Net we have to add bearer token in request header like this `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accesstoken);`